# Webpack imports-loader not working "Cannot find module"

Tags: webpack, gsap

The GSAP library that I am loading requires access to the document object. I have research many solutions, but none have worked. How do I expose the document object to that plugin (or to all plugins)?

This page for instance: http://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html
explains three potential solutions. For me, each one yields a different error message.

If I write import

```
{TimelineMax} from 'imports?this=>window!gsap';
```

I get the error

```
Cannot find module 'imports?this=>window!gsap'
```

The problem is not unique to GSAP; it happens with every library. Imports loader is not recognized by webpack. Even though it is in package.json, has been installed, and other loaders work fine.

```
"imports-loader": "0.6.5",
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us the full stack trace? It would be interesting where the error is coming from.

Comment: Also: Have you tried using `require()` just to pin-down the problem? It should definitely work with `require()`. Do you have an `imports` folder inside your node_modules?